# Create texture image from mesh location

Tags: texturing, scripting, shaders

I'm stuck on an issue, that I hope some of you can help me with.
I'm trying to create 4 texture images, that hold XYZ values (+more) for a mesh. The problem is that I'm not 100% how it should be saved, nor how I'd go about it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/838emnytm3dbow1/shader%2Bdds.zip?dl=0
Link to shader + dds texture.

It's basically a crawler track belt. It consists of joints, and it's the position and rotation of those joints I need to save. It's for the game Farming Simulator. I've included the shader that interprets the texture, and an original .dds file from the game. The array texture consists of 4 textures. The first one I know is the Y and Z locations, saved as blue and green. That can be seen in the bottom here:

[image]

This belt has 90 joints, so it's 90 pixels wide.

The second image I believe to be the rotation, saved as quaternions. Red and Alpha channel go between 0-1.

My second problem is what the 3rd and 4th picture actually do, and how they should be created. 3rd is very similar to the 1st, and 4th is very similar to the 2nd. I believe all the info is within the shader, but I have very limited knowledge and understading of such, to really know what it should do.

The whole idea is for the belt, that can be seen below, is just a flat mesh, but it is then curved by the trackArray texture using the shader. And in the game the mesh will scroll in the new shape, to create a nice belt for your tractor.

[image]

I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQ5Dllbxbz4) video on youtube, and he does sorta what I need to do through a script. So I'm fairly confident it can be done through a script in Blender. Can anyone take a look at the shader, and hopefully give me some pointers as to how it should be saved, and maybe how to go about the script?
It would be much appreciated.

Thank you.